# Rails: JS elements not working after clicking on links using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using adminkit in for my rails(7.0.4.2) project and when I'm using `link_to` to redirect to a particular page, the js elements stop working. Icons don't show up, sidebar drawer stops working, etc.

I tried all the solutions for turbolinks (changing `DOMContentLoaded` to `turbolinks:load`), even removed the gems but nothing worked.

Comment: rails 7 should be Turbo, not Turbolinks, so first of all try to disable turbo (everywhere, then selectively using `data-turbo="false"`)

Comment: This seem to work for me. Thank you @MarianTheisen 
Also, is there a way to not use turbo by default ?

Comment: You can disable drive by using `Turbo.session.drive = false`. https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#disabling-turbo-drive-on-specific-links-or-forms